# Mybatis Spring Batch : how to delete from mutliple tables with where clause in Tasklet?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-batch, mybatis

I want to do multiple deletes from various tables like this :

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE T1_ID = :id AND T1_CREATION_DATE IS NULL;
DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE T2_ID = :id AND T2_CREATION_DATE IS NULL;
COMMIT;
```

but with spring batch.

so far I tried :

```
String query = "DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE T1_ID = :id AND T1_CREATION_DATE IS NULL;"+
"DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE T2_ID = :id AND T2_CREATION_DATE IS NULL;"+
"COMMIT;";

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    jobContext = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();

    Employee employee = (Employee) jobContext.get("employee");

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    parameters.put("id", employee.getId());

    new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource).update(query,parameters);

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

it is compiling but i got a bad SQL grammar exception, i think it is because JdbcTemplates does not manage transactionnal query.

Any hint ?

PS : for my readers and writers I use Mybatis, is there a way he can handle the multiple delete ? I tried but I was unable to use mybatis sql statement in the Tasklet

Comment: Execution should already be transactional, have you tried removing commit? And using update() method twice as you have two queries?

Comment: Thank you for your response, removing commit has not worked and I must do it in the same transaction, this is a requirement

Comment: Yes but I think Spring batch starts a transaction before executing tasklet and terminates it after (I may be wrong though, but that seems legit).

But I was right, update method takes only one query at a time : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-

Comment: Why can't delete by using seperated one?

Comment: @Nghia Do because i think it's not proper and optimized, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your help, i managed to make it work.

at first, i did it with separate templates like this :

```
protected String expDelete = "DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = :id AND CREATION_DATE IS NULL";
protected String dipDelete = "DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = :id AND CREATION_DATE IS NULL";

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("id", employeeInTreatment.getId());

new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.dataSource).update(expDelete,parameters);
new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.dataSource).update(dipDelete,parameters);
```

it kinda worked (compiling but the deletions were not commited). But i was convinced i could do it in one go.

I created a service and a dao pointing to my mybatis mapper :

```
employeeBatchDao.deleteEmployeeImportedData(employeeId);

<delete id="deleteEmployeeImportedData" parameterType="Integer">
   {call
       declare
       begin
           DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = :id AND CREATION_DATE IS NULL;
           DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = :id AND CREATION_DATE IS NULL;
       end
    }
```

i called it in my tasklet and it worked ! now i can make all my deletes in one go !